# Prove the set $\Bbb Z^+ \times\Bbb Z^+ \times \Bbb Z^+$ is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove the set $\Bbb Z^+ \times \Bbb Z^+ \times \Bbb Z^+$ is countable.

I know you can use diagonal processing to prove that $\Bbb Z^+ \times \Bbb Z^+$ is countable, but how would you go from there?

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb Z_+\times \Bbb Z_+\times \Bbb Z_+$ ?

Comment: User matcounterxamples.net's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1572305/finite-cartesian-product-of-countable-sets-is-countable) gives the idea how to go from product of two to product of finitely many.

Comment: I meant the + to be a superscript here

Comment: Or AlexBecker's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127695/proving-that-a-set-is-countable-by-finding-a-bijection/127792#127792).

Comment: You may show that $$(a,b,c)\mapsto a+\binom{a+b-1}{2}+\binom{a+b+c-2}{3}$$ is a bijective map from $\mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+\times \mathbb{Z}^+$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$ , for instance.

Comment: Map the triple $(a,b,c)$ to the number $2^a 3^b 5^c$. This is an injection (1-1 function) by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, ie unique factorization into prime powers. So the triple product of the naturals fits nicely inside one copy of the naturals. Same trick for any finite product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there exists a bijection $f\colon \Bbb Z^+\times \Bbb Z^+\to\Bbb Z^+$, there also is a bijection $\Bbb Z^+\times \Bbb Z^+ \times \Bbb Z^+ = (\Bbb Z^+\times \Bbb Z^+)\times \Bbb Z^+\to \Bbb Z^+\times \Bbb Z^+$, and so also a bijection 
$$ \Bbb Z^+\times \Bbb Z^+ \times \Bbb Z^+\to\Bbb Z^+\times \Bbb Z^+ \to \Bbb Z^+$$
namely $(x,y,z)\mapsto f(f(x,y),z)$.

Answer (score 0):

I have given this answer already two or three years ago.
Let me repeat. Instead of constructing a bijection, I'll indicate how to  give 1-1 function, call it $\phi$, from the 3-fold product to positive integers.

Instead of a formula for such a function, I'll write out the function for a specific element. You can figure out how to do it in general.

Here we go. What is $\phi(7,4,14)$?

Consider  numbers written in base 11, where we use the digits $0,1,2,\ldots, 9$ as usual, and for number TEN we use the COMMA symbol. 
So $(7,4,14)$ after stripping off the parentheses represents a 6-digit number in base 11. It is the number
$$ 4 + (1\times 11) + (10\times 11^2) + (4\times 11^3) + (10\times 11^4) + (7\times 11^5)$$
This number is defined as $\phi(7,4,14)$.

As base expansion is unique this is a 1-1 function.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+$ is countable, there is an injective map from $\mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$.
It follows that there is an injective map from $\left(\mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+\right)\times \mathbb{Z}^+$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+\times \mathbb{Z}^+$.
By composition of injective maps, there is an injective map from $\mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+\times \mathbb{Z}^+$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$,
hence $\mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+\times \mathbb{Z}^+$ is countable.

If you replace *injective* with *bijective* and find a bijective map from $\mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$, you also get a bijective map from $\mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+\times \mathbb{Z}^+$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$. The one listed in the comments is a chance.